# Windows Jenkins service org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles

Tags: java, windows, resources, swt, gdi

**The problem input:**

- I have a 64bit Windows based desktop application developed in Java with SWT.
- Using Task Manager I can see the number of GUI handles: aprox. 900 **User Objects** and 1700 **GDI Objects**. The numbers remain on the same level for the entire run of the application.
- The maximum number of allowed User Objects and GDI Objects on my system is 10k each. I figured it out in by viewing the *GDIProcessHandleQuota* and *USERProcessHandleQuota* registry.

Running the application (once or multiple times in parallel) normally with the current user does not generate any kind of a problem. Everything runs as expected.

**The problem**:

The problem (SWTError: No more handles) appears when I try to run the application within a **Jenkins started as a service**. I know that within a windows service the application does not display any GUI, however it still "grabs" User Objects and GDI Objects. After a few seconds I keep getting all sort of *"No more handles related"* errors like this one bellow:

```
11:08:40.315 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
11:08:40.315 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
11:08:40.315 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
11:08:40.315 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
11:08:40.315 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:482)
11:08:40.315 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:718)
11:08:40.316 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.createHandle(Composite.java:292)
11:08:40.316 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createHandle(Decorations.java:430)
11:08:40.316 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.createHandle(Shell.java:593)
11:08:40.316 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:758)
11:08:40.316 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.createWidget(Scrollable.java:151)
11:08:40.316 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createWidget(Decorations.java:439)
11:08:40.316 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:300)
11:08:40.316 WARN - org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:379)
11:08:40.317 WARN - org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.createShell(Window.java:482)
11:08:40.317 WARN - org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:425)
11:08:40.317 WARN - org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1096)
11:08:40.317 WARN - org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)
11:08:40.317 WARN - org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:396)
11:08:40.317 WARN - org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.open(MessageDialog.java:424)
11:08:40.317 WARN - org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog.openError(MessageDialog.java:520)
11:08:40.317 WARN - app.widget.ui.WidgetTab.openError_aroundBody0(WidgetTab.java:605)
11:08:40.317 WARN - app.widget.ui.WidgetTab$AjcClosure1.run(WidgetTab.java:1)
11:08:40.317 WARN - org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:167)
11:08:40.317 WARN - util.aspects.MessageDialogAspect.proceedToDialog(MessageDialogAspect.java:221)
11:08:40.317 WARN - util.aspects.MessageDialogAspect.handleMessage(MessageDialogAspect.java:90)
11:08:40.317 WARN - util.aspects.MessageDialogAspect.ajc$inlineAccessMethod$util_aspects_MessageDialogAspect$util_aspects_MessageDialogAspect$handleMessage(MessageDialogAspect.java:1)
11:08:40.317 WARN - util.aspects.MessageDialogAspect.openError(MessageDialogAspect.java:50)
11:08:40.318 WARN - app.widget.ui.WidgetTab.displayWidget(WidgetTab.java:605)
```

**The investigation so far:**

- I used *Testlimit* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/testlimit) tool but it wasn't very conclusive so I created my own small windows test app which creates as many windows and brushes as it can (***CreateWindiowsEx*** and ***CreateSolidBrush***) afterwards it prints the last error.
- Running the test app with the current user it can generate close to the max value of 10000 User Objects and GDI Objects respectively. The last error: (code 1158) *The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects.*
- Running the test app within Jenkins: the creation of windows stops at around 1700 (User Objects) whereas the creation of brushes goes to maximum of 10000 (GDI Objects) both with the same error: (code 8) *Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.*

**Questions/Expectations:**

- The investigation leads me to other limitation other than the expected one when exceeding the maximum number of objects since the creation of User Objects breaks way before reaching the maximum.
- Is there any *"hidden"* limitations regarding GUI handles in the Windows service? I couldn't find any documentation regarding this, apart from those pseudo-docs posted in the Materials section.
- Why does the test app "grabs" 10k user objects when started by the user and just 1700 when started by the SYSTEM service?
- I expect to find out there is a limitation by the service but I cannot figured it right now. Any thoughts? Thanks!

**Materials:**

- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/09/29/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles/
- https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/214732

**UPDATE**

Regarding the error log, as I stated above "keep getting **all sort** of *'No more handles related'* errors". I just put another log message not to get confused by the *MessageDialog.openError* which is present in the first log.

```
12:01:14.661 ERROR - org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Item not added
12:01:14.661 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
12:01:14.661 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
12:01:14.661 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
12:01:14.661 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:482)
12:01:14.662 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu.createItem(Menu.java:533)
12:01:14.662 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem.<init>(MenuItem.java:134)
12:01:14.662 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.fill(ActionContributionItem.java:257)
12:01:14.662 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.doItemFill(MenuManager.java:728)
12:01:14.662 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.update(MenuManager.java:810)
12:01:14.662 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.updateAll(MenuManager.java:932)
12:01:14.662 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.update(MenuManager.java:830)
12:01:14.663 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow.createTrimWidgets(ApplicationWindow.java:355)
12:01:14.664 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow.configureShell(ApplicationWindow.java:341)
12:01:14.664 ERROR -    at app.ui.Gui.configureShell(Gui.java:544)
12:01:14.664 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.createShell(Window.java:493)
12:01:14.664 ERROR -    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:425)
12:01:14.664 ERROR -    at app.ui.Gui.create(Gui.java:584)
12:01:14.664 ERROR -    at app.ui.Gui.open(Gui.java:275)
12:01:14.665 ERROR -    at app.GuiController.init(GuiController.java:411)
12:01:14.665 ERROR -    at app.GuiController.main(GuiController.java:260)
12:01:14.783 ERROR - Exception in thread "SWT Thread"
```

Comment: That stack trace seems to show that the code is actually trying to display an error message dialog. So it is doing GUI activity.

Comment: The application how it was built it is supposed to open/close several MessageDialog during it's runtime so I expected GUI activity. I know that it shouldn't be this way but at this point the refactoring is not a solution. I still need to find out the exact limitations of the service (which are not to be found), maybe it's a settings solvable problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @greg-449 indicated, your process is trying to create a GUI control (error message Shell) from a windows service. By default, windows services are not allowed to interact with the desktop, you have to put a SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS service flag to make them able to do so, check [Windows documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services) for details. But my guess is that you did not intend to show UI from a Jenkins task, so you have to debug why the app attempts to show an error dialog.

The message `No more handles` is misleading in this case.

Take a look at the SWT source for `Control.createHandle`:

```cpp
    void createHandle () {
        long hwndParent = widgetParent ();
        handle = OS.CreateWindowEx (
            widgetExtStyle (),
            windowClass (),
            null,
            widgetStyle (),
            OS.CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, OS.CW_USEDEFAULT, 0,
            hwndParent,
            0,
            OS.GetModuleHandle (null),
            widgetCreateStruct ());
        if (handle == 0) error (SWT.ERROR_NO_HANDLES);
        ...
```

As you can see, the `SWT.ERROR_NO_HANDLES` error is thrown in any case when `OS.CreateWindowEx` fails and returns zero - in your case, because of running a non-interactive service. There's no actual check if User or GDI handle limit is exhausted.

Comment: Your guess is right: I don't want any GUI interaction while the application is started as a service. The application during it's runtime opens and closes (automatically) several MessageDialogs, this is the way it is supposed to work. Indeed MessageDialog.openError suggests that something went wrong but still I don't think this is the root cause of "No more handles". It may be the case here but this also happens in other cases, without MessageDialog.openError occuring. I updated the question with a new log. Why can 'CreateWindowsEx' fail?

Comment: I can see "org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create" in the new stack trace. Apparently, that code attempts to create some UI.